# JavaScript to click buttons automatically in a sequence in a different page

Tags: javascript, button, triggers, click

I am trying to auto click a button that redirects to a new URL, and from there click a button. Both buttons need to be clicked one after another; however, the latter executes as soon as the first starts executing. I need it to wait and then execute. Is this possible to achieve since both buttons are getting triggered from the different pages?

They are of both domains, I did use async and wait, but it still doesn't wait for the other link to load fully and then trigger the button. I want the first button to completely load the page and then trigger the next button.

basically, I am trying to follow users from another user's follower list. In the list, you have to visit first the follower's profile(first trigger) and then follow the use(second button). Is there a better approach to do this?

Code:

```
var draft = document.getElementsByClassName('follow__name');
        console.log(draft.length)
        console.log("draft = ", draft)
        draft[2].click(); //<-button number
        console.log(draft[2]) 
        document.getElementsByClassName('Button_label__3jCra')[5].click();
```

Comment: Are both sites on the same domain and/or can you alter both sites?

Comment: They are of both domain, I did use async and wait, but it still doesn't wait for the other link to load fully and than trigger the button.

Comment: is there a reason as to why you can't just call the logic which clicking them would call?

Comment: Yes, so basically I am trying to follow users from another users follower list. In the list you have to visit first to the followers profile(first trigger) and then follow the use(second button). Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Yes, implement the actual logic where you need it. If you want to keep it on multiple sites I recommend [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) over triggered DOM clicks.